# What is 'context' in mongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am new to Mongo Atlas and on its GUI I have seen that my projects are under a category called 'context'. So what is context?

[image: image from MongoDB Atlas GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I asked the same question on the MongoDB Atlas chat box and they answered it...

This is the answer:

The context box is Atlas lists your organisations and projects. 
Within your organisations, you have your projects. An organization can contain multiple projects. You may find the MongoDB Atlas documentation on [Orgainsations and projects](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/organizations-projects/) helpful.